# Do I put my license/copyright header on top of a permissively-licensed file I found on the internet?

Tags: apache-2.0, license-notice, derivative-works, psf

I found a nice Python class on a website devoted to nice Python gists - and on its web page (but not in the source code) it has the author's name and says it is [PSF licensed](https://opensource.org/license/python-2-0) - which wikipedia says is BSD-style and even allows for proprietization.

I fixed a bug and added a feature.  But it is >90% the same code.

What I want to do is include it in a repo where all the code is covered by Apache 2.0 license, and where all the code has it's own license/copyright header - which claims copyright for the company owning the repo and names Apache 2.0 as the license

I certainly put a header at the top of it naming the contributor, naming the PSF license, and including the URL where I found it.

Can I/Do I *also* put our company license/copyright header (described above) on it?

Comment: 1. For this topic, probably https://opensource.org/license/python-2-0 is a better reference source than Wikipedia. 2. Could you link to the the actual PSF license text that applies to your case?

Comment: @Brandin - TY, done

Answer (score 1):

Including the file in an otherwise Apache-licensed project is fine. For clarity sake, if there is a central location that states that all source code is under the Apache 2.0 license, I would recommend that you add something like "unless noted otherwise" there.

What you cannot do is just blindly slap a copyright notice and Apache license header on a third-party file. But you *can* license your changes to the file under the Apache license and add the license/copyright header for that reason.

Comment: To license the _changes_ to the file is it sufficient to say something about "changes relative to the source at the such-and-such URL" or do I have to mark/notate the lines somehow?

Comment: @davidbak, it is even sufficient to state something like "adapted from" where you have the link to the original project.